# I want to send email using google smtp server. But it always showing SMTPAuthenticationError

Tags: python, server, smtp

I want to send a mail after reading a specific a row from a excel file. I did as per rules i got on web. But my code is not working rather showing "smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials s13sm4935540pfm.12 - gsmtp'" error. I have gone through multiple solution but none has worked in the end.

```
server.connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()

password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
print(type(password))
X = "from@gmail.com"
Y = "to@gmail.com"
server.login(X, password)

df = pd.read_excel(r'D:/Topu/files/Allocation.xlsx')

fc = df.iloc[:, 0]
try:
    server.sendmail(X, Y, fc)
    server.close()
except:
    print("failed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your gmail account and enable the 'Allow less secure apps' to this link that will fix this. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1